# Can't remove subview from superview-Xcode6

Tags: objective-c, addsubview, superview

I added a view (displayTapeView)to the superview via Storyboard and it's working fine. But when I want to remove displayTapeView when clicking the "Back"button on the displayTapeView. It doesn't work. My current code is as below:

```
- (IBAction)tapeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
self.displayTapeView.hidden=NO;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
//[[self displayTapeView] removeFromSuperview];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.displayTapeView cache:YES];
self.displayTapeView.layer.masksToBounds=NO;
self.displayTapeView.layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(-15.0,20.0);
self.displayTapeView.layer.shadowRadius=5.0;
self.displayTapeView.layer.shadowOpacity=0.5;
//[[self view] addSubview:_displayTapeView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
[[self displayTapeView] removeFromSuperview];

}
```

What I want to do is when "Back" button is clicked, the displayTapeView is removed and the superview is shown.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try hiding the view instead of removing it. Your purpose will be solved with this I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.displayTapeView.hidden = YES;
```